# Smoke from power tool battery charger

Tags: voltage, transformer, battery-charging

I have a DeWalt power tool battery charger. It's rated for 120V, drawing .5A but I used it with a transformer converting 240V to 120V. At first I used it on the low setting (<26W) but it took too long to charge. When I switched it to the hi setting, the charger made a popping sound and smoke came out. On inspection, the pcb inside had a little brown fluid on it, and a largish capacitor seems a little puffed up.

[The transformer is a small device - made in China, distributed by Target, 220/240V to 110/120V AC 50hz. It has a low setting for < 26W and high setting for up to 1875W]

A) Why did this happen?

B) Is it safe to 1) plug it in 2) insert a battery 3) can it ruin the battery

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think I fully understand, *"...but I used it with a transformer taking 240v."* Could you please be a little more descriptive? Also, the circuit looks pretty easy to follow. Do you think you could be bothered to draw out a schematic? Is it possible that the fuse blew? (Easy to check with a meter.) There are lots of possibilities. See if you can winnow them down a bit for us?

Comment: That's a nice one. What's on the flip side of that PCB? I can see a primary capacitor, probably shitty, you could try replacing that one *with some quality model*. I'm no expert in these chargers - the photo makes me wonder why there's no secondary side capacitor, apparently. As if the charger just rectified the output straight into the cells... The charger could still be basically alive, or it could overdrive the trafo into saturation on "high" setting, or it could have a short in the trafo, whatever... If you ask this way, I suggest that you stay away from that piece of crud :-(

Comment: This seems to be a fairly common issue on these chargers, see this video for example. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdDbvRJfEAw I'd start by replacing the bad capacitor, then test it out if it works.

Comment: BTW my thumb up for your taste in the choice of title. Did you know the theory that all electronics works, in principle, based on inner containment of smoke? If the smoke leaks, the device stops working.

Comment: That video linked by @Klas-Kenny is to the point and contains the necessary safety warnings. The one thing I advise against is purchasing dubious capacitors at a discount. I suggest Nichicon CS or CY, or a similar Panasonic model - try downloading some datasheets and compare their nominal ESR / permitted ripple current. "Just any capacitor" is definitely not a good replacement here.

Comment: @Klas I am notoriously careful about safety, to the annoyance of electronics people... but I say those talents are well spent doing "like-for-like component repair" of UL listed equipment.  Provided replacement parts are RU-Recognized, to retain its UL Listing.

Comment: @Klas-Kenny: but what will stop it from happening again? Why couldn't it handle the transformer's output?

Comment: "Used it with a transformer” so 120 to 230 or 230 to 120?

Comment: Obviously if you supplied this with 230VAC and it was designed for 110VAC, then assume that everything is now dead, including the regulator IC, the electrolyte cap and all diodes on the primary side.

Comment: I'm inclined to believe that the OP has in fact NOT subjected the charger to 240V. Rather, he probably did the right thing and used a transformer to obtain 120V from 240V mains. I've seen PSU's mistakenly switched to 120V and operated off 240V - those primary caps had a very particular look to them :-) and the sound they made was more like a gunshot.

Comment: A note to the OP: if the transformer provides 120V, it is probably not to blame. I'd put the blame to a low-quality elyt - those 68uF / 200V on the primary side. Possibly overloaded by too much AC current on the "high" setting. The "MOSFET" is possibly an all-in-one PWM controller + FET (TopSwitch or some such), unless there's more on the underside of the PCB. If the thing shows no signs of life after replacing the primary cap, get a new charger.

Comment: Ohh yes there's a lot more on the flip side. I've found a photo. A number of SMD components. I can see about 4 SO8 or similar packages. Could be a PWM controller, could be individual transistors, could be op-amps, or a dedicated charge controller IC... Try the large capacitor and see if that helps. This is possibly the primary-side PWM controller SMD: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.net/datasheet-pdf/view/861011/DIALOG/IW1710-01.html If that's the case, the TO220 package is indeed a bare MOSFET.

Comment: _”When I switched it to the hi setting”_ I’m not aware of any DeWalt charger with any such setting. Exactly what did you switch and in what configuration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Klas-Kenny in comments above has [the inside track on repairing your unit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdDbvRJfEAw).

But now let's talk about that "transformer".

### Your transformer wasn't a transformer

And it wasn't UL/BSI/TUV Listed, either.  It was a cheap thing, probably mail-order.  When you say you switched it from "low" setting to "high" setting, you are referring *to the "un-transformer"*, because the charger doesn't have a switch like that.

I would suggest acquiring an *actual, literal transformer*.  These are notable because they are rather heavy and are actually doing transforming, and will reliably deliver 110-120V at all loads within its ability.

That cheapo "non-transformer" was a cheat device.  By all means do a destructive teardown on it if you can't send it back, as it should never be used. These cheap things typically have two modes selected by the switch:

- "Low" uses an actual transformer for low power.  Which is great, but there isn't very much of it because of the very small transformer. It is for nothing bigger than a wall-wart.
- "High" uses some sort of very simple/cheap silicon scheme to clip off parts of the 230V sinewave, to reduce total power delivered. Very cheap, and doesn't work for any but the most basic resistive loads.

Switching it to "high" put it in "garbage power but more of it" mode, which the charger simply could not handle.

Avoid adapters like that in the future.  Buy such things at reputable retail shops who stand behind their products and answer to regulators in your country. Such items will have competent instructions, follow them and you should be fine.

Though, just between you, me and the wood post... actual proper transformers that weigh 10-20 kilo, that come in metal boxes, are hard for the Chinese to mess up too badly. The weak point on those is their universal "everything socket", which is useless in 230V continents since the only 120V plug is NEMA 1-15 or 5-15.  So change the hokey everything-socket to a quality Leviton NEMA 5-15 (which accepts 1-15).

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I live in a comfy fishtank where I've seen a 240/120V transformer like twice in my life... I appreciate the warning that dark and dangerous things live outside of my comfort zone :-(

Answer (score 1):

A) That device has a switch mode power supply which is rated for 120VAC input. The power supply bulk input capacitor is rated accordingly to 200VDC which is suitable only for 120VAC input. Applying 240VAC means the capacitor ratings were exceeded, about 340VDC was applied to 200VDC capacitor. Too much voltage caused it to heat up and boil the electrolyte in it and as the pressure in it grew enough the capacitor "puffed up" and electrolyte leaked out via the seals. Good thing it did not explode with a loud bang.

B) The capacitor is damaged, and even if it is replaced, it is unknown how other parts have been affected by the overvoltage. I would say it is 1) not safe to plug a damaged device it into mains, or 2) not to insert batteries into possibly damaged charger and 3) damaged charger may damage batteries.

The last thing you want are damaged batteries, as damaged batteries can be dangerous (short themselves, heat up, start a fire or explode).

Comment: I used the transformer to convert the 240 to 120; using the transformer's LO setting (< 25W) it worked, but seemed to charge too slowly. The HI setting blew the charger, but was should have still been outputting 120V to the charger.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica maybe you should tell which transformer you used, it might be a thing in your parts of the world but not here. You mean some sort of travel adapter which is not meant for anything else than shavers, right?

Comment: updated the info

Comment: @ReinstateMonica It does not tell much but usually those devices read with big warning text that they are not suitable for any electronic equipment and they should be only used with hair dryers or similar devices. Did your device come with instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Like all lithium battery packs, the battery *should* be fully self-protected against most perils (deep discharge, overcharging, excess current) and I’d be highly confident that DeWalt batteries are.  Similarly the charger will be designed so that line voltage doesn’t get anywhere near the battery even in a fault condition.  However, with what sounds like that big electrolytic capacitor popped and possibly other damage that we don’t know about there’s nothing to be gained from plugging the charger in to an AC supply because it’s blown, and therefore little point in doing so.